# How is it possible to send commands to other program from python?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, popen

Here is the problem: I need to start a program and send there commands from python.
For example it may be cmd and I send there path to cd and dir the contains(work on windows).
I tried lots of ways but cannot still find the solution.

I can't understand why it isn't working even on simpliest examples.
I came to conclusion that subprocess.Popen may be the best way for my goal.
Here is what I tried.

In first block of task the program only prints the contains of the directory of python file instead of given and in second block it prints nothing for some reason

Please may be anyone knows how to do it the right way?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


if __name__ == "__main__":

    path_for_dir = "C:\\Users\\Documents"

    class Console:
        def __init__(self):
            command = r"dir"
            self.console = Popen(
                command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, text=True
            )

        def read_output(self):
            result = []
            for line in self.console.stdout:
                result.append(line)
            for line in result:
                print(line)

        def cmd(self, cmd_string):
            self.console.stdin.write(cmd_string)
            self.console.stdin.close()

    c = Console()
    c.cmd(f"{path_for_dir}")
    print(c.read_output())

    print(f"NEXT")

    p = Popen(
        ["grep", "n"],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stdin=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE,
        shell=True,
        universal_newlines=True,
    )
    p.stdin.write("one")
    p.stdin.write("two")
    p.stdin.write("three")
    testresult = p.communicate()[0]
    print(f"{testresult=}")
```

Comment: What command(s) do you actually want to send, and what output do you need to get back? If you really want to read a directory listing, use `os.listdir` or `os.scandir`. The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) suggests you should use `subprocess.run` unless you need to do something complicated.

Comment: Nekomatic, thank you for your comment, I tried to explain what I need just on simpliest examples, but actually I need to start another application and send from python command one-after-one there for execute

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not writing newlines in the one-two-three example at all. All grep sees is `onetwothree`. (That said, `onetwothree` would still match `n`, but I assume you do mean different lines since you have three different write calls.)
2. You shouldn't use `shell=True` unless you need to. You can use `shutil.which()` to find a command like the shell would.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from shutil import which

p = Popen(
    [which("grep"), "n"],
    stdout=PIPE,
    stdin=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
)
p.stdin.write("one\n")
p.stdin.write("two\n")
p.stdin.write("three\n")
testresult = p.communicate()[0]
print(f"{testresult=}")
```

prints out

```
testresult='one\n'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I copied your code and somehow it doesn't work for me. It returnes a TypeError :  expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType,... I added prints in code and they gave out None results for commands that are not executable files, look: which("dir")=None
which("grep")=None
which("cmd")='C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.EXE'
which("python")='C:\\Users\\olgas\\Documents\\interpreter\\Scripts\\python.EXE'

Comment: Well, right, I assumed you have `grep` on your path, since it certainly isn't a default command in Windows. For commands that are shell internals, you will need `shell=True`.